# Rule to enforce closure of child tasks before epic can be closed

Tags: azure-devops

I know that you are able to set up rules around the process in your organisation. I need to ensure that epics cannot be closed if any child items are not closed. However, none of the rules I've tried so far appear to work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: How's the progress about this ticket? Does below explanation have any help to you?  Free to share comment below if still has puzzle or question on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Rule to enforce closure of child tasks before epic can be closed

I'm afraid what you expected are are still not available in Azure devops.

See this feature request: [Do not close a user story unless all tasks are closed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/802993/do-not-close-a-user-story-unless-all-tasks-are-clo-1.html).

You can vote it which can increase its priority. Because our product group consider to take it into our develop roadmap based on this.

---

Since this feature does not available until now, you need write some customized code to around this by making use of client api.

See this [blog1](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/automation-of-state-changing-for-azure-devops-work-items-based-on-states-of-child-work-items/) or [blog2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/733985/Close-a-Work-Item-Only-if-Child-Work-Items-are-C-3) sample.

What its working logic is using WIQL to listen the relative linked items, if they are all not closed when someone want to close the parent item. The system will forbidden the parent item closed.

Refer to this [UpdateParentState.cs](https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomNetTasks/UpdateParentState/UpdateParentState/Program.cs) file to confirm whether it could helpful for you.